# Resourceful Route Order of Laravel - Does it matter?

Tags: laravel

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Give the below order by default

```
photos.store
photos.index
photos.create
photos.show
photos.update
photos.destroy
photos.edit
```

But should we organize our routes as below mentioned ? 
Does the order matter ?

```
photos.edit   //photos/{photo}/edit
photos.update //photos/{photo}/update
photos.create //photos/create
photos.show   //photos/{photo}
photos.destroy//photos/{photo}
photos.index  //photos
photos.store  //photos
```

Comment: It only matters that the `create` route comes before the `show` route. The rest are technically unique because they're using different HTTP verbs.

Comment: @RossWilson I am unable to award the best answer since your answer is in the comment section

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should **order your routes with the most specific first**. Anything with a parameter should be considered a wildcard, matching all routes.

In the above example, that's what is being done and therefore, there is no problem. An other factor you should notice is - the HTTP verb being used. For example, even though, below have same urls, but the verbs are different (`GET` and `POST`)

```
photos.index  //photos
photos.store  //photos
```